# Plotting multiple time-series in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a time-series dataset consisting of 10 variables.

I would like to create a time-series plot, where each 10 variable is plotted in different colors, over time, on the same graph. The values should be on the Y axis and the dates on the X axis.

[Click Here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/co.csv) for dataset csv

This is the (probably wrong) code I have been using:

```
c.o<-read.csv(file="co.csv",head=TRUE)
ggplot(c.o, aes(Year, a, b, c, d, e,f))+geom_line()
```

and here's what the output from the code looks like: [image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I wasn't able to find anything in previous threads.

PROBLEM SOLVED, SEE BELOW.

One additional thing I would like to know:

Is it possible to add an extra line to the plot which represents the average of all variables across time, and have some smoothing below and above that line to represent individual variations?

Comment: you might need a separate question for your last comments. There are several ways to achieve this. One way would be have another level in  `variable` for example called `meana_f`, you would then be plotting this with the same logic you would `a` or `f` in the current plot.

Comment: Can you print head() of the initial .csv file, because the link you provided says file not found?

Comment: Can you please provide the original dataset?

Comment: data set is missing

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If your data is called `df` something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
meltdf <- melt(df,id="Year")
ggplot(meltdf,aes(x=Year,y=value,colour=variable,group=variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

So basically in my code when I use `aes()` im telling it the x-axis is `Year`, the y-axis is `value` and then the `colour`/`grouping` is by the `variable`.

The `melt()` function was to get your data in the format `ggplot2`  would like. One big column for `year`, etc..  which you then effectively split when you tell it to plot by separate lines for your `variable`.

Comment: for some reason I get the following error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Year' not found and before this when I added the melt() command it said: > meltdf=melt(c.o)
Using  as id variables

Comment: also is there a way to make the lines look 'nicer'? these abrupt jumps look a bit like they were confidence intervals...can it be made a bit more continuous?

Comment: the jumps are your data.. you could take means for the years within groups i.e. `cast()` after `melt()`, plot a smoothed function of the data or coarsen the year scale one the x axis but that is really up to you and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: ok, but why do I get the error mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: I missed something in the code you should use `meltdf<-melt(df,id="Year")`.  I corrected this above too.

Comment: Or you can use `geom_smooth`, possibly in combination with `geom_point` to get a smoother graph.

Comment: How could we plot each variable yearly and using variable as facet_wrap?