# plot each column of a dataframe on the same line graph in r

Tags: r, plot, model, ggplot2

I have a dataframe and would like to plot the values (aggregated residuals) by column on the same line graph in R. The dataframe has 1000 columns and 323 rows.

I found how to do it one series at a time by using ggplot, but I am having trouble figuring out how to plot all of them without having to do it one at a time. Does anyone have any ideas?

The data looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdWmK.jpg

(i didnt have the reputation to post images)

Comment: You want to plot 1000 lines on one graph?! Also, there must be literally hundreds of questions on Stackoverflow about line plots. I feel you haven't searched very hard.

Comment: you can use `matplot()`, or you can use `reshape2::melt()` and then use `ggplot()`.

Comment: E.g. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324004/plotting-multiple-time-series-in-ggplot

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started: Assuming your `data.frame` is called df:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
D=melt(df, id='id')
ggplot(D,aes(id,value, group=variable, color=variable))+geom_line()
```