# working on search queries in R

Tags: r, plot, timestamp, searchqueryset

I'm new to R, but try to analyze dataset 
Here is the original link https://cache-default03g.cdn.yandex.net/download.yandex.ru/company/jobs/test_data_dreams.txt

My code is (I use R Studio 0.99.903 & R 3.3.1)

`# get the data from url
    url <- "https://cache-     default03g.cdn.yandex.net/download.yandex.ru/company/jobs/test_data_dreams.txt"
    testdata <-read.table(url, header = T, sep="\t") 
    #install packages for text mining to analyze the queries
    install.packages("slam")
    install.packages("tm")
    library(tm)
    #convert unix to GMT
    testdata$timestamp..unix. <-        as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(testdata$timestamp..unix.)),origin="1970-01-01",tz="GMT")
    #delete some words
    testdata$query <- gsub("к чему снится ", "\\1", testdata$query)
    testdata$query <- gsub("к чему сниться ", "\\1", testdata$query)
    testdata$query <- gsub(" к чему снится", "\\1", testdata$query)
    testdata$query <- gsub(" к чему сниться", "\\1", testdata$query)
    testdata$query <- gsub("снится ", "\\1", testdata$query)
    testdata$query <- gsub(" к чему", "\\1", testdata$query)'`

Now my data frame looks this way.

`> head(testdata)
         timestamp..unix.                          query         city
     1 2016-02-04 10:15:13         волна вынесла на берег       Москва
     2 2016-02-24 10:28:53             бегать наперегонки Екатеринбург
     3 2016-02-07 15:31:51 свадьба мужчине со своей женой  Владикавказ
     4 2016-02-05 08:06:24             иголка медицинская       Тамбов
     5 2016-02-16 15:21:16                давняя знакомая  Калининград
     6 2016-02-27 03:38:46        белый маленький котенок  Новосибирск`

Now I'm trying to plot queries to see their distribution during the daytime (also during the month) in general and for each city I have.

Could you please help me with the tool I should pick to read days and hours separately and plot not the query itself, but just the distribution of queries.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Yevgenyia, welcome to stack overflow. In order to get the help you need, the question you post should contain an example of the data set you are using (or simply a part of it, if it is too big), the attempt you made to solve the problem and the code you used. Have a look at the following link on [how to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). If you edit your question, I am sure we can help you out :)

Comment: @thepule Thank you for the link! It made everything more understandable )

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/lubridate.pdf)** package, it is quite easy to extract days and hours from your dates and then to make a test on them. For example :

```
 # Add a column for day
df$day <- day(df$timestampcol)

# Add a column for the hour
df$hour <- hour(df$timestampcol)
```

For the plot I recommend you **[ggplot2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/ggplot2.pdf)** package, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324004/plotting-multiple-time-series-in-ggplot) you will find a example plotting time series.